# Where are the screensaver settings in Unity?

Tags: screensaver

Why is there no screensaver in the default installation of Ubuntu 13.04 ? I've found that it can be installed afterwards, but I don't understand why this feature is not present by default. Has the concept of screensaver been replaced something else ? Is there a discussion somewhere where I could find an explanation for this ?

How do you install a screensaver ? Does Unity even have screensavers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for screen-savers in today's day and age. They were used to prevent [CRT burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in). Turning LCD entirely off will prevent burn-in too and save a good amount of energy.

If you still want to install a screen-saver then read this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/114027/how-to-add-screensavers-to-ubuntu-12.04/).

Comment: Do LCD screens consume the same amount of energy regardless of what is being displayed ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the content is (ie. the amount of "blackness") it **will** depend on the brightness it is setup though. Also, standby-mode and even turned off will be best.

Comment: What about LED screens? They're getting common too. Any idea about that?

Comment: Most screens that are sold as "LED-screen" are [LED-backlit LCD screens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED-backlit_LCD_television). The cold cathode fluorescent backlight is being replaced with a LED backlight and the LCD will chooses which subpixel gets how much light. Thus you don't conserve energy with more blackness on the screen. This is changing, since newer monitor will regionally dim the LED-backlight, but well. Most monitors still don't have that feature and my first comment still aplies.

Comment: A screen-saver tells you at a distance that your computer is running.